# error: use of undeclared type '$__lldb_context' in NSAttributedString extension

Tags: swift, lldb

Given the following Swift code, saved in bug.swift, and using Xcode 8.2.1 or Xcode 8.3 beta 2:

```
import Foundation

protocol MyProtocol {
    func foo() -> String
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func foo() -> String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}

extension String: MyProtocol {}
extension NSAttributedString: MyProtocol {}

let normal = "normal".foo()
let attributed = NSAttributedString(string: "attributed", attributes: [:]).foo()
```

Run the following commands:

```
swiftc -g bug.swift
lldb bug
```

LLDB launches. Now, run these commands, and observe the output. Where I pass `9`, pass the line in your `bug.swift` that contains `return "\(self)"`:

```
(lldb) target create "bug"
Current executable set to 'bug' (x86_64).
(lldb) b 9
Breakpoint 1: where = bug`(extension in bug):bug.MyProtocol.foo () -> Swift.String + 19 at bug.swift:9, address = 0x0000000100001e53
(lldb) run
Process 16370 launched: '/Users/zev/Desktop/bug' (x86_64)
Process 16370 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x31730e, 0x0000000100001e53 bug`MyProtocol.foo(self="normal") -> String + 19 at bug.swift:9, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100001e53 bug`MyProtocol.foo(self="normal") -> String + 19 at bug.swift:9
   6    
   7    extension MyProtocol {
   8        func foo() -> String {
-> 9            return "\(self)"
   10       }
   11   }
   12   
(lldb) po self
"normal"


(lldb) c
Process 16370 resuming
Process 16370 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x31730e, 0x0000000100001e53 bug`MyProtocol.foo(self=0x00007fff5fbff480) -> String + 19 at bug.swift:9, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100001e53 bug`MyProtocol.foo(self=0x00007fff5fbff480) -> String + 19 at bug.swift:9
   6    
   7    extension MyProtocol {
   8        func foo() -> String {
-> 9            return "\(self)"
   10       }
   11   }
   12   
(lldb) po self
error: <EXPR>:1:11: error: use of undeclared type '$__lldb_context'
extension $__lldb_context {                            
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: <EXPR>:18:5: error: use of unresolved identifier '$__lldb_injected_self'
    $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_2(     
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The first time we hit the breakpoint, we're in `String`'s conformance to `MyProtocol`, and we can successfully `po self`.

However, the second time we hit the breakpoint, we're in `NSAttributedString`'s conformance to `MyProtocol`, and LLDB prints gibberish instead of the expected output from `po self`.

Why does LLDB sometimes fail to print anything useful? This is a contrived example, but I run into this all the time in my day-to-day use of LLDB.

Comment: Filed a [Swift bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3886) at [Joe Groff's suggestion](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/828979787150422018).

Comment: Clearly a bug.  This is tricky because the self in a protocol has no static type.  So the debugger can only print self if it can resolve the runtime type of the object.  With objects crossing from ObjC->Swift that's not entirely trivial, as your example shows...

Comment: This bug has been resolved in some recent version of Swift 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://github.com/apple/llvm-project/issues/4395#comment-44337) on the Swift bug reporter, the bug was fixed at some point. I tested in Swift 5.2, and confirmed that it's fixed

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the bug, following my exact steps from the original question. If you are, maybe you've found a different but related bug? If you can find good repro steps, you could post it to bugs.swift.org :)

Comment: It happened while debugging a watchOS app, the debugger is quite useless in that case lol

Answer (score 1):

After reopening Xcode and clearing the project the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue:

```
error: <EXPR>:1:11: error: use of undeclared type '$__lldb_context'
extension $__lldb_context {
```

even without any compiler bugs.

Ensure you set your Xcode Command Line Tools to match the currently running version of Xcode, in your Xcode -> Preferences (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>).

[image: Xcode CLI Tools]